# How to change table font size

Tags: tabulator

How to change `tabulator` table font size? [There](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.4/style#sass) is no description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like kind of solution

```
.tabulator { font-size: 12px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Refer](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.4/style#sass)
Here they have specify a variable **textSize** under general.you can try this one.

textSize - The text size for all text in the tabulator